# Incorrect key path for S3 using Paperclip to persist image from URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, paperclip

I have images uploading to S3 from a user selected file and it works. I want to add saving images from URLs to the database as well. I get the following error:

```
[AWS S3 404 0.103582 0 retries] head_object(:bucket_name=>"my-bucket",:key=>"merches/merch_photos//medium/c211d05de2831cba60fa31ac21e9d52a_m.jpg") AWS::S3::Errors::NoSuchKey No Such Key
```

My guess is that the // in the key path is the problem. There should be something like 000/001/234 in between those two slashes. That's how it works for file uploads and it's what the :id_partition should be doing.

In my paperclip.rb initializer I have

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:url] = ':s3_domain_url'
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:path] = '/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename'
```

In my model I have

```
def picture_from_url(url)
  self.merch_photo = URI.parse(url)
end
```

In my controller I am assigning the photo property in the create method like so:

```
@merch.picture_from_url(params[:merch][:merch_photo])
```

In my config I have

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
 :storage => :s3,
 :s3_permissions => :public_read_write,
 :s3_credentials => {
   :bucket => Rails.application.secrets.my_bucket,
   :access_key_id => Rails.application.secrets.my_aws_id,
   :secret_access_key => Rails.application.secrets.my_aws_secret
   }
 }
```

Everything looks correct as far as I can tell and the general setup should be fine since regular uploads work. However with URL uploads, I get the error with the improperly formatted key. Any ideas?

Comment: Has the object been saved at this point (ie does it have a non-nil id?)

Comment: No it has not been saved. The log shows a db rollback.

Comment: I mean at the point where it was trying to upload the attachment

Comment: Params show :id => nil but other params have good values. So no, the object doesn't get saved.

Comment: Presumably that's your answer then - if the object's id is nil then id_partition isn't evaluated to anything sensible then

Comment: yikes! thanks, and now I get to chase down why it's not saving.